# Resize bokeh plot from CustomJS

Tags: django, bokehjs

Resize bokeh plot from CustomJS.

```
window.setXYDimension = function (width, height) {
  fig.plot_width  = width;
  fig.plot_height = height;
  console.log({fig});
  fig.reset(); //reset doesn't exist
  fig.resize(); //resize doesn't exist
  fig.layout(); //layout doesn't exist
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do. Is it anything like as in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614866/how-to-delete-add-rows-in-bokeh-heatmap-and-maintain-row-height

Comment: @smiley Thank You for the comment. Would like to update the bokeh plot, width & height from js dynamically? Will check the shared sol. Right now, using `plot.model.attributes.width = width` to update the plot width at Frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
window.setXYDimension = function (width, height) {
  fig.frame_width  = width;
  fig.frame_height = height;
  fig.properties.width.change.emit();
  fig.properties.height.change.emit();
};
```

Thank You to [Smiley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5542253/smiley) for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `CustomJS` as well to resize figures on an event

```
CustomJS(args=dict(plot1=p1), code="""
plot1.width=1500;
plot1.height=1500;
plot1.document.resize();
"""
)
```